# Oracle DB query to get records count and calculate average afterward

Tags: oracle

Could anyone please help me regarding that Oracle query.
Here is my required output. [image]
Thanks in advanced.from below query return some record i want to Calculate 
Average means SUM(COST+DURATION)/No.of row return form that query but below query doing partition based on SITE_ID i dont want any partition,What is want is whatever query return (Sum of all Duration+sum of all Cost/No. of row returns)but without any partition is that any way i can do that

select * from  (
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) RN,
          SITE_ID,
          CASEID,
          WOID,
          DURATION,
          COST,
          (SUM(COST+DURATION) OVER(PARTITION BY SITE_ID))/COUNT as TotalCost from

```
     (
      SELECT  COUNT(*) OVER () as COUNT,
      SITE_ID,  
      CASEID,
      WOID,
      ROUND(table1.duration/3600,2) AS DURATION,
      ROUND(table2.duration/3600),2) AS COST
       FROM table1  ) AVG
```

WHERE (1=1)
   ) 
where rn between 0 and 1000

Comment: Your query seems incomplete.  Please show us the exact code you are using.

Comment: First i get that total no. of count in that query then I have to calculate Average but I'm not able to get total no. of count which is return by that query

Comment: Please show sample input and output data.

Comment: I updated my query as right now I'm doing is SUM(Cost+Duration)/RowCount but not getting expected result.Could you please help me.You can check above query I also attached scrrenshot

Comment: I added my sample query in that can u modifiy that bcoz we are using that format only i want to calculate SUM(COST+DURATION)/RowCount retruns from that query

Comment: Your desired output includes SITE_ID, DURATION and COST as well as an calculated average misleadingly titled TOTALCOST.  Those figures exist at two different granularities. You either need an analytic function (which you say you don't what) or you need to decide which columns you want to GROUP BY.

Comment: Ok even if i keeping it if u able to see screenshot its not even calculating properly

Comment: Once again you have edited the question and overwritten the formatting. This is called *failure to learn.* If your question is hard to read it's less likely to attract helpful responses.

Comment: [Some sample data would help.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve) 
 Also [the code above is really hard to read.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode)

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of your revised question what I think you want is the total of COST and DURATION for each SITE, plus an average of these figures derived from the number of entries in `table1` and `table2`. This is what this query does:

```
select site_id
       , duration
       , cost
       , (duration+cost)/no_of as avg_total_cost
from (
    select
      table1.site_id
      , count(*) as no_of
      , sum(round(table1.duration/3600,2)) as duration
      , sum(round((table1.labor_rate * table2.duration)/3600,2)) as cost
    from table1
    inner join table2
        on table1.id = table2.id
    group by table1.site_id 
)
/
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f254/5) to prove that this query runs successfully.

---

Your question appears to reference other tables, `site` and `emp`, which I have ignored because you don't provide join conditions for them. Likewise I have ignored the top-n filter; you can add it back it if you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i tried that one getting error likeORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: I added my sample query in that can u modifiy that bcoz we are using that format only i want to calculate SUM(COST+DURATION)/RowCount retruns from that query

Comment: This is my last guess. If this doesn't provide the answer you want please edit your question to example the business logic you need to implements. It is hard to reverse engineer rules from some shonky code. Also provide sample data which will produce the output you posted.

Comment: Is that any way i can do without partition i want to calculate like whatever query return over a specif period of time let say in one month it will get some 50 records what i want is (Sum of All Duration(all 50 records) +SUM of all COST(all 50 record)/no. row (50)

Comment: Of course that can be done, that is trivial. The problem is, your projection contains additional columns which apparently exist at a different granularity to the sum you want to calculate. You need to resolve that inconsistency, and explain clearly the business rules for **your whole query** and not just the aggregate column.